# Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel /Mongodb

Tags: ajax, mongodb, laravel

i am calling my function from Ajax,

```
 $loggedin=Session::get('userid');
    $proj_id= $request->proj_id;   
    $proje_wbs = Project_WBS::where('projectid', '=', $proj_id)
    ->where('subid','=',$loggedin)- >get();
    return $proje_wbs->wbs;
```

But it shows "Trying to get property of non-object" please any solution?

Comment: Can you do `dd($proje_wbs)`? I think it's null.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check first if `$proje_wbs` exists

```
$proje_wbs = Project_WBS::where('projectid', '=', $proj_id)
->where('subid','=',$loggedin)->get();

if ( $proje_wbs ) {
    return $proje_wbs->wbs;
}
```

However, this is still not going to work but the error will be different. Because you are using `get()`, your query will return a collection, meaning `$proje_wbs` is not an object; therefore you cannot access properties like `$proje_wbs->wbs`.

If you need want your query to return an object, use `first()` instead of `get()`:

```
$proje_wbs = Project_WBS::where('projectid', '=', $proj_id)
->where('subid','=',$loggedin)->first();

if ( $proje_wbs ) {
    return $proje_wbs->wbs;
}
```